# Linq: How to group by maximum number of items

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

## CONTEXT

- I have a list of items (or arbitrary length). I'd like to group them in 'chunks' of a certain size
- Example: I have 12 customers [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] and want to group themin chunks of 5 which would give [0,1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8,9] [10,11]
- NOTE: In reality I am not working with customers or monotonically increasing integers. I picked that just to simplify asking the question

## MY QUESTION

How can I formulate a straightforward LINQ query (using query syntax) that performs this grouping?

## BACKGROUND

- I'm already familiar with how to use LINQ syntax for grouping by a value for example (to group sales by customer id), however I am at a loss how to express the 'chunking' cleanly/elegantly using LINQ. I am not sure if it is even possible in a straightforward way.
- I can and have already implemented a solution in plain-old-C# without using the LINQ syntax. Thus, my problem is not being blocked on this question, but rather I am looking for ways to express it in LINQ (again cleanly and elegantly)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can group them by (index/chunkSize). Example:

```
    var result =
        from i in array.Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index })
        group i.Value by i.Index / chunkSize into g
        select g;
```

Comment: This is one of those rare cases where a plain for loop and a dictionary is shorter AND more comprehensible than LINQ...

Answer (score 4):

For those who prefer the LINQ methods (with lambda expressions), here is [Dimitriy Matveev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1258192/238722) converted:

```
var result = array
    .Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index })
    .GroupBy(i => i.Index / chunkSize, v => v.Value);
```

If you need just an array of `value`, instead of an `IGrouping<T1, T2>`, then append the following:

```
.Select(x => x.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

**Extension method** (using [Jesse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24814436/2094687)):

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> GroupToChunks<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int chunkSize)
{
    if (chunkSize <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Chunk size must be positive.", "chunkSize");
    }

    return
        items.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
             .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / chunkSize, pair => pair.item)
             .Select(grp => grp.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do the actual grouping, shouldn't it be:

```
var result = array
.Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index})
.GroupBy(i => i.Index / chunk, v => v.Value);
```

Comment: Steven - you're correct. I've updated my answer. Thanks for catching that. Also, please note that StackOverflow (StackExchange as a whole too) isn't forum style, where you reply to the "above" reply. You posed to answer to the question. I realize you probably didn't have enough rep to add a comment. So, anyway, just trying to help out.